# How to use j2objC for conversion in iOS code?

Tags: android, ios, j2objc

I want to use my android code for i OS. I have seen many links recommends using of j2objC translator. But i don't know how to use this translator. can any body tell the all steps involved in this conversion??

I need the step-wise method

Answer (score 2):

J2ObjC is a sophisticated tool and requires a certain amount of setup. You must have access to the source code and experience as a software engineer. The best starting point is the documentation:

https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Rather than "It's a bad question, you need to get more experience," (which may be completely valid, granted), it would be more helpful to explain "It's a bad question, for the following reasons, this is a better question, and how to go about answering it." Does that make sense?